# Match Value in Cell to an Existing Column and Return Adjacent Cell Text

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet containing patients in column a, patient's diagnosis in column b, and their doctor in column c. I have another sheet that has the doctors listed in column a and their practice group in column b. I need a function that will look at each value in column c on sheet 1, match it to the doctor in column a on sheet 2 (Doctors List), and return the practice group to column d on sheet 1. I have tried a few formulas including this one

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,'Doctors List'!A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

but can't seem to get anything to work! It just returns blanks. Please help!

**SHEET 1

```
Patient Name   Diagnosis    Attending Physician    Practice Group**
Patient A      Diagnosis    Dr. Smith   
Patient B      Diagnosis    Dr. John    
Patient C      Diagnosis    Dr. Joe 
Patient D      Diagnosis    Dr. Ken 
Patient E      Diagnosis    Dr. Williams    
Patient F      Diagnosis    Dr. Williams    
Patient G      Diagnosis    Dr. Smith   
Patient H      Diagnosis    Dr. Jones
```

**SHEET 2

```
Physician          Practice Group**
Dr. Smith          Practice A
Dr. John           Medical Group A
Dr. Joe            Practice B
Dr. Ken            Medical Group B
Dr. Williams       Practice C
Dr. Jones          Medical Group C
```

Comment: check whether your doctor names are exactly the same (e.g. there is no any additional spaces in the beggining, in the end and in the mid of the word) and also try: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(C2),'Doctors List'!A:B,2,FALSE),"")`

Comment: For some reason this works perfectly for my made up data in a spreadsheet, but I cannot manage to get it to work in my previously created spreadsheet. I hate to think I'd have to re-type all of that stuff!

Answer (score 8):

Try using MATCH and INDEX rather than VLOOKUP

So in D2 of sheet 1:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,MATCH($C2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0))
```

and copy that formula down.

If you're looking to troubleshoot, your existing formula, try using "Evaluate" on the Formulas tab of Excel 2010 which can step you through the calculation.

I've had problems with text fields that have extra spaces after them, so I regularly use the "TRIM" function when doing lookups, or matches.

Comment: Found that index does not work with table references. Also if you get errors when adding the index portion try removing the `$` symbols from the formula. Like `=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH($C2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0))`

Comment: I use Index / Match on table references all the time.

Comment: For example       =INDEX(Table1[Number],MATCH(A1,Table1[Letter],0))

Comment: I believe the first part of the formula should be

    Sheet2!$B:$B

Instead of

    Sheet2!$B:B$

Comment: Corrected.  Thanks.

Comment: This also works for LibreOffice Calc but change the ! to .